# yii2 Module class must be properly namespaced

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I have duplicated `/frontend` folder into `/api` removed unnecessary code like `views`. And then I started to generate using `gii` the new module eg: `v1`

I got this error message when using `api\modules` namespace.

```
Module class must be properly namespaced.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not be aware but in the Yii2 framework there is a `common/config/bootstrap.php` file which holds the aliases eg: `@frontend`, `@common`

Just add another line for the `/api` folder section and it would be good.

```
Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('@frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('@backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('@console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
```

Comment: well, the alias could be added to the `params-local.php` file too if you want to, and it would be detected in the `gii` module.